# IntelliJ Idea mapstruct java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: intellij-idea, mapstruct

After upgrading to the version 2020.3 of Idea i get a NullPointerException for the mapping processor. If anybody has a clue... Thank you!

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The solution is to update MapStruct to 1.4.1.Final or later version, [see this issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2215) for more details.

You can also add `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` at File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Build process VM options as a workaround.

Comment: After upgrading Mapstruct to 1.4.1.Final I am getting another issue which I did not get with 1.3 - "No method found annotated with @Named#value". Has anyone faced this problem yet?

Comment: You just need to add the @Named annotation over the method and qualifiedByName where it was used.

Comment: IDE should not be the driver to force lib update on a project.

Comment: Thanks, adding ```-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false``` really helped me!

Comment: After upgrading Mapstruct to 1.4.1.Final I am getting another issue which I did not get with 1.3 - "No method found annotated with @Named#value", and i have this method in parent class (inheritance). these methods are there for long time

Comment: I would add : also update `mapstruct-processor` to 1.4.1.Final or later version

Comment: We have the same problem with mapstruct 1.2 Final on windows, if we run the test directly on the java class.  -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false fix our problem.

Answer (score 161):

If you cannot update MapStruct (my case), [details here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2215).

You have to find the exact place where put the `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` setting (and I had hard time to figure out where).

So, as they say, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Open Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler and write ps.track.ap.dependencies=false]
**Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler**

Comment: flawless answer @freedev

Answer (score 19):

There are several intellij bugs here. If I change the maven version 1.3.0.Final  to 1.4.1.Final the intellij don't want to update the version.

**Solution**

1. Upgrade the maven version to 1.4.1.Final
2. Delete manually mapstruct 1.3.1.Final from External Libraries(Project Structure | Libraries)
3. mvn clean package
4. Click reload all maven projects

It works without -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false

If you have swagger exclude mapstruct first:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
<version>${swagger2.version}</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: Manually removing the old version from the external libraries and reloading the Maven projects worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [freedev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67269707/6224662) answer. For windows users the following will be the place to go :

1. Click on the settings gear icon on the right.
   [image]
2. Go to settings (ctrl+A+S is a good shortcut to get here).
3. Find Compiler under Build,Execution, Deployment in the left menu
   [image]
4. Add `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` in User-local build process VM options

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I made these changes and it works perfectly for me.

[image]

[image]

Then I just deleted the caches and rebuilt the entire project, maybe it wasn't necessary but that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my build.gradle was misconfigured. I used some Mapstruct SPI AccessorNamingStrategy in two separat projects (command and custom-mapper) which I included twice in annotationProcessor of the build gradle.
My solutions was to remove one of the annotations and it worked.