# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "resource" is null at org.mapstruct

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mapstruct

mvn compilation using Idea works fine.

Fails during App.main start.

Works well on older Idea on other PC on Ubuntu.

ENV:

- Intellij 2020.3.2 as admin;
- Java 15.02;
- Windows 10 x64;
- latest mapstruct.

How to fix this?

```
D:\back\src\main\java\io\x\mapper\Mapper.java:15:8 java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "resource" is null
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.createManifestUrl(DefaultVersionInformation.java:182)
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.openManifest(DefaultVersionInformation.java:153)
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.getLibraryName(DefaultVersionInformation.java:129)
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.getCompiler(DefaultVersionInformation.java:122)
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultVersionInformation.fromProcessingEnvironment(DefaultVersionInformation.java:95)
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.DefaultModelElementProcessorContext.<init>(DefaultModelElementProcessorContext.java:50)
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:218)
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:156)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor207.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.APIWrappers$1.invoke(APIWrappers.java:248)
at lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1025)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:940)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1269)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1383)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1261)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:935)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:231)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:501)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:353)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:277)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:231)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1441)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1100)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1224)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1066)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.access$1200(IncProjectBuilder.java:67)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder$BuildParallelizer$1.run(IncProjectBuilder.java:1006)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Please properly format your stack trace.  Look for the first mention of your code to see the statement in your code that caused the exception.  You will find that it is passing a null value to whatever API it invokes.

Answer (score 27):

In your Intellij IDEA:

```
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | user-local build process vm options
```

set this value :

```
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your solution! Can you explain with more details why this works ?

Comment: I can update This answer works for 
mapstruct 1.5.3.Final 
Intelij 2022.3.3 Ultimate Edition Build #IU-223.8836.41, built on March 10, 2023

Answer (score 11):

I had a problem with MapStruct in Intellij 20.3.2. Error *Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "resource" is null[...].*
I did a little research and saw that it was enough to just change the version in pom.xml. Here on the documentation website we can see the package installation configuration:https:**//mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/**
There was still an error in the following excerpt:

```
  <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>

  <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>

  <version>**${org.mapstruct.version}**</version>
```

Finally, placing the following version in  **1.4.2.Final**  ran the application smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

Please update to the current IDE and MapStruct versions. This issue [was fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250718#focus=Comments-27-4418347.0-0) long time ago.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65113549/104891) for the workaround.

Comment: Hello, Serge! No, it was not fixed. I have latest Idea as you see and mapstruct.

Comment: What MapStruct version do you use? Does `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` option help?

Comment: 1.4.2.Final. How to apply mentioned option? Preferences ->  Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler
User-local build process VM options (overrides Shared options):
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false=========> new error.

Comment: Feel free to report at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues.

Comment: Make sure that you also update the mapstruct-processor version as well. This bug has been fixed a while ago in MapStruct

Comment: updating to latest version of mapstruct-processor fixed this error for me...

Answer (score 1):

Please update newVersion mapstruct

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using same versions of mapstruct and mapstruct-processor:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```