# How to update mapstruct dependency in Intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, jhipster, mapstruct

I am trying to update a dependency in IntelliJ. Unfortunately, IntelliJ always loads the dependency with the old version.

At the beginning I was wondering because the application runs fine when I start it with Maven.
But when I want to start it with IntelliJ I get the following error:

> IntelliJ Idea mapstruct java: Internal error in the mapping processor:
> java.lang.NullPointerException

---

**After all solutions I have tried, Maven always shows the old version 1.3.1.Final in the Dependency:Tree. What I have tried:**

**1)** I quickly found a similar question ([IntelliJ Idea mapstruct java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112406/intellij-idea-mapstruct-java-internal-error-in-the-mapping-processor-java-lang))

- Upgrade the maven version to 1.4.1.Final
- Delete manually mapstruct 1.3.1.Final from External Libraries(Project Structure | Libraries)
- mvn clean package
- Click reload all maven projects

**2)** Trying to have IntelliJ automatically reload the change:

- Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Reload project after changes in the build scripts: From "External Changes" to "Any Changes"
- Then I changed the version in the pom file from 1.3.1.Final to 1.4.1.Final

**3)** Trying to have IntelliJ automatically reload the change, trial number 2:

- Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Generated sources folders: "Detect automatically"
- Then I changed the version in the pom file from 1.3.1.Final to 1.4.1.Final

**4)**  Clear the cache in IntelliJ:

- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

**The snippets of the pom file:**

```
<properties>
      <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
</properties>
```

...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-annotation-processor -->
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT: You can see the full pom.xml file via [this link.](https://pastebin.com/nzvrn0Z6)**

**EDIT2: Probably the version is pulled from the Jhipster dependencies.**

Pom snippet:

```
<!-- Dependency versions -->
<jhipster-dependencies.version>3.9.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
```

Siehe: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/3.9.1

**Why the explicit version in the properties does not overwrite the version of the parent pom (JHipster dependencies)**

Comment: please show the full pom files... snippets don't really help...

Comment: The definition of the version is probably from the `jhipster-dependencies` bom.

Comment: you are right. I will edit the question.

Comment: Try running `mvn dependency:tree` this should show you why a certain version of a dependency is loaded.

Comment: For me, that was exactly the confusing part. I think I'm reading the dependency tree wrong. For me it looks like the mapstruct version 1.3.1.Final is from the Pom.xml of the project. 
Here the console output: https://pastebin.com/Y59AJijr

Answer (score 1):

Your POM does not have an explicit version.

The property `<mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>` is only useful if it is used somewhere (it does not automatically change a version).

Comment: But why is it not explicit? I thought it would be Option 2 from this site https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot.

Comment: It is only explicit, if at some place, there is `<version>${mapstruct.version}</version>`, e.g. in the parent POM.

Comment: ok but there is a place...in <annotationProcessorPaths>. But I think the parents POM overrides this, isn't it?

Comment: You are injecting the dependencies defined by jHIpster through a POM import. Using a property does not override the version from the parent POM. In addition to that parent POM cannot control what is in `annotationProcessorPaths`