# JHipster: "Unspported Source Version" on debug in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, jhipster

My JHipster app runs correctly after command mvn spring-boot:run, but I have problem with debug it on Intellij Idea. Below error message apears on some Mapper class. [image: Error message]

On different project with the same dependencies and settings everything works fine. I'm using Java 8 in my pom.xml.

[image: Pom.xml]

Mvn clean and mvn clean install didn't help. What should I do to run debug correctly?

Comment: Don't copy error messages and source code as images.  Use text and mark as code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It could be a bug in the MapStruct processor which is fixed in 1.4.1.Final. Please upgrade to that version or do as described in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250718#focus=Comments-27-4418347.0-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ Idea mapstruct java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112406/intellij-idea-mapstruct-java-internal-error-in-the-mapping-processor-java-lang)